# plot data on a map

Tags: r, data-visualization, spatial

I’ve a data set contains three variables: longitude, latitude, population (in USA). I need to plot this data on a map. I use the following R code (it works fine):

map("state", xlim = range(lon), ylim = range(lat))

text(lon, lat, population)

box()

But the thing I’m facing is that the map looks really ugly, and It’s hard to read since data displayed on the map are mixed with each other.

I was wondering if there is a better way to plot these data on a map.
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't cross-post, http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/28262/751

Answer (score 1):

Within R check out the [ggmap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/index.html) package, which utilizes the visualization power of [ggplot2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html) to create beautiful, informative map graphs.  See [example](https://sites.google.com/site/davidkahle/ggmap) plots.